# How to prove that $H^\infty$ is weak star dense in $BMOA$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I know $H^\infty \subset BMOA \subset H^2$ and $BMOA$ is dual of $H^1$. I know how to prove that $clos_2[H^\infty]=H^2$, here $clos_2$ is the closure in the $H^2$ norm, but I do not know how to prove that the weak star closure of $H^\infty$ in $BMOA$ is $BMOA$.

Can anyone suggest me some references or write down the proof if it is too trivial. Any kind of help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well it suffices to show that if $f\in H^1$ and $\langle g,f\rangle=0$ for all $g\in H^\infty$, then $f=0$.  I'm not too familiar with Hardy spaces, but this is a general method for showing a subspace of a dual space is weak$^*$-dense.

Comment: If each $g \in H^\infty$ annihilates $f \in H^1$, then $f=0$. I do not understand how will it work?